# Get the range of the whole word document including all stories

Tags: ms-word, vb6

How can I get the range of the 'whole' document including all stories as `wdMainTextStory, wdFootNotesStory, wdEndNotesStory` etc. And also I need to get the range of `wdFootNotesStory`. 
I have tried sevaral ways.

```
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
Selection.WholeStory
```

This only select the whole wdMainTextStory. If anybody could, please help me to go through this.

Comment: Is this really a VB6 question?  In any case I think a Story is as big as a range can get, i.e. I don't think a range can span multiple Stories.

Comment: it is a VB6 question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Funny, sounds like an Office Automation question.  The answer is the same in any language capable of using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to get the range of FootNotes.

```
dim objRange As Word.Range

For Each storyRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    If storyRange.StoryType = wdFootnotesStory Then
        objRange = storyRange
    End If
Next storyRange
```